# Admob does not work

Tags: c#, admob, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to make something like in this video using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khlROw-PfNE , but I don't have using Admob, I've got GoogleMobileAds, and it doesn't allow me to use

```
Admob.Instance().initAdmob(BannerId,videoId);
```

And more , it even doesn't give the option to type Admob.Instance

Thanks for Help

Sorry For Bad English

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use admob namespace.

Write this line on above:

```
using admob;
```

Comment: i dont have framework using admob it only allows me to use googleAdvertisment as you can see in pic

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the framework into your class, you can do it buy using the

```
using admob;
```

keyword. Or you can directly access to the framework and do something like:

```
admob.Admob.Instance().initAdmob(BannerId,videoId);
```

Comment: @Max_Powe89 i dont have framework using admob it only allows me to use googleAdvertisment as you can see in pic

Comment: if you followed the tutorial that you posted, at the minute 7.39 you can see that he is using the admob framework. If you want to use a method that is in the ad mob framework you have to import it.

Comment: i fixed it , i needed to use whole different code. Can you help me out with my Share Script Please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301836/unity-sharing-facebook-twitter-whatsapp-e-t-c-android

Comment: If you fixed the problem, mark and vote the answer so you can close the question :). later I should have some time to look at the other problem