# Unity Sharing Facebook,Twitter,whatsapp E.t.c Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

Hello i want to share my game on twitter and Facebook , this script allows me to share details to twitter , whatsapp but i cant share on facebook it doesnt show text on facebook , but on twitter and whatsapp it does , And i dont know how to add in To script so it takes screenshot of game and Adds it to post Please help me out

Sorry for bad English

And Here is ShareScript.

Thanks for help :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class ShareMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool isProcessing = false;

    private string shareText = "Download This Game";
    private string gameLink = "Download the game on play store at " + "\nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.CrazyDrivers";
    private string imageName = "MyPic"; // without the extension, for iinstance, MyPic 
    public void shareImage()
    {

        if (!isProcessing)
            StartCoroutine(ShareScreenshot());

    }

    private IEnumerator ShareScreenshot()
    {
        isProcessing = true;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D(1080, 1080, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
        screenTexture.Apply();


        string destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".png");
        Debug.Log(destination);

        if (!Application.isEditor)
        {

            AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
            AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
            AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
            AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + destination);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), shareText + gameLink);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/jpeg");
            AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

            currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);

        }

        isProcessing = false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try your script, but the problem may be in facebook sharing policy. [Here is some information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill).

Long story short — facebook does not allow prefilled text.
[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)